# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

i am trying to work on a project which has multiple components. Example app is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-az46xg). I am in a situation where i am getting the error in the development mode as follows

[image: Error]

I know why this error is coming

> Because after the child component values are bound , parent component
>   values are  updated by grandparent component, resulting in throwing of
>   error during angular dirty check

The skeleton of my app is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-az46xg). Can someone please help me resolve this issue. I know it could be solved by using setTimeout or changeDetectionRef. But thats not a solution i am looking for, i want to know what am i doing wrong during the life cycle hooks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to hear that you are against `setTimeout` and manually calling `detectChanges`.

I know that this is obvious in your app structure but here is an example that show you where the error comes from:

https://ng-run.com/edit/d9EEfZLhGfM0fYQtehhs?open=app%2Fgrandparent%2Fparent%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html&layout=2

> Because after the child component values are bound , parent component
>   values are updated by grandparent component, resulting in throwing of
>   error during angular dirty check

Seems you're right your child component is rendered before ngAfterContentInit happens.

Angular application is a tree of views. When angular runs change detection mechanism it goes through this tree of view and call [checkAndUpdateView](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L350-L383) function for each of views.

During execution of this function angular calls other functions in a strictly defined order. In our case we are insterested in these functions:

```
execEmbeddedViewsAction
callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (AfterContentInit)
execComponentViewsAction
```

It means that **angular will call change detection cycle for embedded views(`ng-template` generates embedded view) earlier than executing `ngAfterContentInit` hook**. This is what happens in your example:

[image]

As we can see in the picture above when angular checks AppComponent view it checks embedded views first and then calls `ngAfterContentInit` for `GrandParentComponent` and goes down to `GrandParentComponent` view.

Seems there are many ways to solve it. I tried on of them in this **[Demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/rPFmIjMTFjUJRNxkcuxR?open=app%2Fgrandparent%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html)**

The key moment is not using `ngAfterContentInit` hook but rather set index and active values within `ParentComponent`:

**parent.component.ts**

```typescript
export class ParentComponent {
  private _active: boolean = false;
  public index = 0;

  constructor(
      @Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => GrandParentComponent))
      public grandParentComponent: GrandParentComponent) {
    this.index = this.grandParentComponent.parents.length;
    this.grandParentComponent.parents.push(this)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.active = this.index == this.grandParentComponent.currentStep;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.grandParentComponent) {
      this.grandParentComponent.parents = this.grandParentComponent.parents.filter(x => x !== this);
    }
  }
```

where parents property has been declared in `GrandParentComponent`:

**grandparent.component.ts**

```typescript
export class GrandParentComponent {

  parents = [];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer .. really helped my understanding :) Just a follow up question ,.. if i have to check a condition before setting the active step as follows, https://ng-run.com/edit/L5aa8pGmhqtFPkksK1AE?open=app%2Fgrandparent%2Fgrandparent.component.ts .. how would i be able to do that since the parents in not initialised

Comment: You can pass `length` or the whole `obj` to grand-parent. You can also make grandparent to be responsible for rendering children without transclution through `ng-content`. If you want to provide template in this case then you can use `ng-template` with ngTemplateOutlet directive